# How can we select, in the output select, the queue with the shortest size in anylogic?

Tags: java, queue, anylogic

I want that the select output direct each agent to the queue with the shortest size.

I know that we can use queue.size to know the length but i don't know how to use it in the conditions of the select output.

Thank you A LOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use "select true output" if condition is true

and then, assuming that queue1 is on the true exit, you do

```
queue1.size()<=queue2.size()
```

that will be the condition